# How do I load an image to a picturebox from a URL using basic authentication?

Tags: c#, picturebox

When the URL was not protected at all this following worked well.

```
string imageURL = ("https://api.blah.blah/customers/" + userID.ToString() + "/photo");
pictureBox1.LoadAsync(imageURL);
```

Now that we are behind basic authentication I was hoping I could simply do this:

```
string imageURL = ("https://username:password@api.blah.blah/customers/" + userID.ToString() + "/photo");
pictureBox1.LoadAsync(imageURL);
```

But I am having no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of `PictureBox` is this? wpf, winrt, winforms, sl?